# Not able to do maven release

Tags: java, git, maven, maven-3

I have a multi module project and I am trying to release the all projects. Its always failing on prepare steps.

```
mvn release:prepare -DautoVersionSubmodules=true -s c-settings.xml -X and throwing this exception. [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.1:prepare (default-cli) on project qa-parent: Unable to tag SCM
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] ERROR: Repository not found.
[ERROR] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please make sure you have the correct access rights
[ERROR] and the repository exists.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.1:prepare (default-cli) on project qa-parent: Unable to tag SCM
Provider message:
The git-push command failed.
Command output:
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.

Even though I have all the access in repo. I am owner and admin. Not sure whats wrong here. My scm connection looks like this :

SCM connection:

```
<scm>
<connection>scm:git:git@github.corp.com:FDS/qa-tools.git</connection>
<developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.corp.com:FDS/qa-tools.git</developerConnection>
<url>https://github.corp.com/FDS/qa-tools</url>
<tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
```

Comment: The scm connections etc. are configured correctly cause the message implies there is something wrong...Furthermore i hope you are starting the release process from root parent of the multimodule build...Can you show the folder structure of your project?

Comment: I think the format of the connections is wrong: http://maven.apache.org/scm/git.html - the protocol part (http:// or git://) is not there

Comment: we have this format: scm:git:git://github.com/path_to_repository

Comment: yes. I am releasing from parent project only: All the projects in one dir and parent is on the same level as child. Using ../qa-parent/pom.xml for relative path

Comment: That sounds wrong. Why not having the parent pom within the parent folder?